# Prohibit non-LAN traffic from VPN interface

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, openvpn, iptables

We have a machine running an openVPN client for the sole purpose of being able to SSH to the client while it is connected to a remote network. The VPN is working mostly correctly, but it is routing *all* traffic through the VPN. To not overload our router with traffic during large file uploads to S3 etc, we would like to route traffic through the VPN *only* if it's to an address that's on the VPN's network.

Current output of `route` and `ifconfig`:

```
user@host0:~$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.10.1    0.0.0.0         UG    50     0        0 tap0
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth1
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
192.168.2.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
192.168.10.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     50     0        0 tap0
user@host0:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:04:4b:a7:fa:e5  
          inet addr:192.168.1.223  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::7a45:f5b1:1b87:c6f0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:166634 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:11065 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:37358476 (37.3 MB)  TX bytes:985891 (985.8 KB)
          Interrupt:42 

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:8b:90:06:7c  
          inet addr:192.168.2.100  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:8bff:fe90:67c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:4000  Metric:1
          RX packets:34645 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:107 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:10462790 (10.4 MB)  TX bytes:13440 (13.4 KB)
          Interrupt:132 Memory:50100000-50120000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:4953 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4953 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:463022 (463.0 KB)  TX bytes:463022 (463.0 KB)

tap0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c6:81:e7:8b:58:00  
          inet addr:192.168.10.2  Bcast:192.168.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::c481:e7ff:fe8b:5800/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:10199 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:409 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:1983982 (1.9 MB)  TX bytes:55419 (55.4 KB)
```

What would be the appropriate `ip route` or `iptables` rule to skip the `tap0` interface unless the traffic is to another address on the VPN's subnet?